# Best option to get read-only access to other Stripe accounts

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm building out a 3rd party solution that requires access to other companies' Stripe transaction. My application will periodically look at this data and generate reports on my own platform, without the user needing to do anything. So far I've found a couple options:

- Using restricted keys: This is the most straightforward but require the user to create a brand new key.
- Using stripe apps: Easier integration. I'm not sure what the UX of the app should be tho considering this is mostly a one way sync of data from Stripe -> my separate platform.
- Using stripe connect: Seems the most involved, but I also don't need any of the payment capabilities provided here.

Any thoughts on what the best path forward here is?

I've tried all these methods out

Answer (score 0):

I believe that officially the best solution here would be Stripe apps, as it allows you to customize your access to the account with the [app manifest](https://docs.stripe.com/stripe-apps/reference/app-manifest) permissions.

I don't think Connect is a good idea in this situation, for two reasons:

- You will have unlimited access to all objects from the account, which I gather you don't need, want, and might even be a concern for your users.
- Since it doesn't sound like you're in charge of payments, some other Connect platform might be, and you can't have multiple Connect platforms for the same  account [since a few years ago](https://docs.stripe.com/connect/oauth-changes-for-standard-platforms).

I get that the restricted key idea would probably be the path of least effort for you. Depending on how capable your users would be, it might be a good idea. In my experience, making users perform a setup which is typically intended for developers always leads to problems, no matter how clear you document the process.

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation for a read-only platform (basically what is considered an "extension") is to use Stripe Apps and just utilize [the backend functionality](https://docs.stripe.com/stripe-apps/build-backend). You could also request Restricted Keys from users as you noted but this is a higher burden than an App installation.

Overall creating a Stripe Connect platform would not be recommended since you aren't going to be involved in payment processing in any form.